# adding multiple marker from json

Tags: android, json, google-maps, dictionary, marker

I'm trying to add multiple marker on google map v2 from json 
here is what i tried so far , but cant get single marker on map.

what i feel like I'm making mistake on adding marker , 
should i add another method for adding marker or that's should go in map ready 
or should i use two separate activity one for google map and another for JSON and if you can suggest some correction over here .

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    HashMap<String, Double> resultp;
    private String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private static String url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1an69r";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> placeList;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Double>> Coordinate;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        new GetPlace().execute();
       placeList = new ArrayList<>();
        Coordinate = new ArrayList<>();
         resultp = new HashMap<>();
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }
    private class GetPlace extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MapsActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("wait bro");
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();

            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();


                String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

                Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

                if (jsonStr != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                        // Getting JSON Array node
                        JSONArray places = jsonObj.getJSONArray("places");

                        // looping through All places
                        for (int i = 0; i < places.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = places.getJSONObject(i);

                            String id = c.getString("id");
                            String name = c.getString("name");
                            String city = c.getString("city");
                            String needle = c.getString("needle");
                            Double lat = c.getDouble("lat");
                            Double lng = c.getDouble("lng");
                            String rating = c.getString("rating");


                            // tmp hash map for single contact
                            HashMap<String, String> place = new HashMap<>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            place.put("id", id);
                            place.put("name", name);
                            place.put("city", city);
                            place.put("needle", needle );
                            place.put("rating",rating);
                            placeList.add(place);
                            //adding to new hashmap 
                            HashMap<String, Double> lace = new HashMap<>();
                            lace.put("lat",lat);
                            lace.put("lng",lng);
                            // adding contact to place list
                            Coordinate.add(lace);

                        }
                    } catch (final JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        });

                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                // Dismiss the progress dialog
                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.dismiss();


            }

        }

    **@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
   for( int i=0;i<Coordinate.size();i++)
        {

           resultp = Coordinate.get(i);
          Double lAT = resultp.get("lat");
            Double lNG = resultp.get("lng");

            //Plot latitude and longitude in the map

            LatLng lk = new LatLng(lAT,lNG);

            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new    LatLng(lAT, lNG)));
            Log.e("PlaceLL",lAT+" "+lNG);

        }**
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you verify that `Coordinate` is not empty in your `onMapReady()` method?  My first guess is that there isn't any data for markers to be added.  By the way, now would be a great time to learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Have you tried calling the `new GetPlace().execute();` on the `onMapReady()` so you are sure the map is initialized before trying to set markers on it? and then have on the `OnPostExecute()` something like `MainActivity.this.addMarkers()`

Comment: `onMapReady` is called before your web service calls which makes the Coordinate empty. try to initialize your map after your asynctask `onPostExecute`

Answer (score 0):

Please call asynTask on Mapready instead of onCreate, and parse JSON on PostExe instead of onDoingBackground. On Mapready make sure that map is ready before ur asyntask is done. If asynTask in OnCreate finish before map is loaded, you will get no marker on map. Same as parse JSON code, put it in onPostExe to make sure that you have result from server.